# Ports and protocols between MID server and internal JIRA server

Tags: jira, integration, servicenow, jira-rest-java-api

I need to enable the integration between ServiceNow and JIRA (hosted internally within customer's environment). The MID server is already set up.

My question is: which ports hast to be open between MID server and company's internal JIRA server and which protocol has to be used in order to establish the connectivity? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Pavlo

Answer (score 0):

By default it will be:

- http - port: 80, 8080
- https - ports: 443, 8443

Need to be verified with Jira team and checked on tomcat server configuration.